# Objective-C: View displays empty Table since API takes time to fetch from Server

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, afnetworking

I have a `TransactionViewController` that during instantiation fetches data from `API` and looks like

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        TransactionsModel *transactionsModel = [TransactionsAPI getTransactionsForYear:2014 AndMonth:9];
        self.transactionsModel = transactionsModel;
    }
    return self;

}
```

The `API` get data as following

```
+ (TransactionsModel *)getTransactionsForYear:(int)year AndMonth:(int)month {
    NSDictionary *transactions = [self getTransactions];
    NSLog(@"transactions: %@", transactions);
    return [[TransactionsModel alloc] initWithJson:transactions];
}
```

and

```
+ (NSDictionary *)getTransactions {
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [RestHelper getSecureManager];
    __block NSDictionary* transactions = nil;

    [manager GET:[appUrl stringByAppendingString:@"rest/transactions/2014/11"] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        transactions = responseObject;
    }    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
    return transactions;
}
```

I am using `AFNewtworking 2.0` in which every call is `asynchronous`, right?

**Question** 
How do I wait to display my `Table` until data is fetched from server?

`P.S` I am new to `iOS` programming and looking for recommended ways to solve these issues. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to turn your complete code into an asynchronous implementation. See my example edit below.

```
+ (void)getTransactionsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSDictionary *responseObject)completionHandler {
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [RestHelper getSecureManager];
    [manager GET:[appUrl stringByAppendingString:@"rest/transactions/2014/11"] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        completionHandler((NSDictionary *)responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

You would also need to call `-reloadData` in your block that you pass when using the method:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        TransactionsModel *transactionsModel = [TransactionsAPI getTransactionsForYear:2014 AndMonth:9 completionHandler:^(NSDictionary *transactions) {
            self.transactionsModel = transactions;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }];
    }
}
```

And in your API:

```
+ (void)getTransactionsForYear:(int)year AndMonth:(int)month completionHandler:^(TransactionsModel *transactions)completionHandler {
    [self getTransactionsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSDictionary *transactions) {
        TransactionsModel *model = [[TransactionsModel alloc] initWithJson:transactions];
        completionHandler(model);
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use completion blocks. You have a useful one in your `getTransactions` method:

```
[manager GET:[appUrl stringByAppendingString:@"rest/transactions/2014/11"] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) { 
transactions = responseObject;
--> RELOAD TABLE HERE: [tableView reloadData]; <--
.
.
.
```

Your table is probably in another class. You can use Notifications and Observers. Basically, you set an observer that listens to a specific notification and, at some point, you post a notification, that observers listens to it and do something. For example:

1. Post a notification when the response arrives (the same place where I suggested you put `[tableView reloadData];` but don't put it if you choose this way):

   `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TransactionResponseArrived" object:self userInfo:nil];`
2. Go to you table viewController and add an observer:

   `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateData:) name:@"TransactionResponseArrived" object:nil];`

   Notice that you have to use the same notification name as above.
3. Also in your table viewController, create the method that is being called when the observer gets the notification (`updateData:`):

   `- (void)updateData:(NSNotification *)notification
   {
       [self.tableView reloadData];
   }`
4. Finally, remember to unload the observer:

   `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:InAppPurchaseDownloadStatusUpdated object:nil];`

   You can do it in your dealloc method if you add the observer in an init method. If you use a the viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear to load the observer, use viewWillDisappear or viewDidDisappear to remove it.

Hope this helps!